# Experiment - focal length of concave mirror in concave mirror

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection, home-experiment

I am carrying out an experiment to find the focal length of a concave mirror at home while watching this [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j8N1Z6338UQ). At the 1 minute 32 second mark, the narrator say that we have to set the distance between the object and mirror such that it lies between $\frac{3f}{2}$ and $\frac{5f}{2}$, where $f$ is the focal length.

I don't understand the significance of these numbers. I have spent hours searching online, and I cannot find an explanation - in fact most websites don't mention these figures at all. Could anyone tell me why these two values are important?

Comment: its just to help make the experiment easier, if you already have a rough value of $f$. So that you cross the $2f$ object-mirror, $2f$ mirror-screen point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to me, these figures **dont' hold** any value as such, the principal focus of a concave mirror can easily be found by determining the point at which any two light rays coming from **infinity**(from a very distant object) tend to **converge or meet**.
*The distance between the focus and the pole of the concave mirror will then give us the focal length.*